# using pandas in organizing my csv file data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large excel file that I need to organize in a certain way (years of climate data), for the sake of understanding my problem, I made a this simple excel file for questions. The data looks similar to this:

[image: excel data]

(basically 4x4 data with an empty row between them) and I want to transform this data to look like:

[image: excel results]

(take each row of data transpose it and then add the second row to it with the `Nan`values) using pandas.

The problem that I faced. when reading the file using `file = pd.read_csv("excel data.csv")`:

1. my first row will be detected as a header.
2. the row that separate the data will be converted to `NaN` and will be confused with the actual `NaN` in my data

I tried different functions including reading/saving the file with no index (`index = False`) i also tried functions like `file.iloc[0].values` , `file.shift(1)` but I wasn't able to figure it out.

To summarize I want to be able to read the file using pandas then save it as 1 column that include all the data with no extra information or headers (sorry but I am new to pandas).

EDIT: This is how it looks in jupyter notebook.

[image: data in jupyter]

For the first problem `header = None` worked.

I tried `file.stack(dropna=False).reset_index()[0]` but the results stayed the same as in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `header = None` in the `read_csv` function, it will not detect the first row as header, i.e. `file = pd.read_csv("excel_data.csv", header=None)`

For the second part, once you have the data into the dataframe, you could try this -

```
file.stack(dropna=False).reset_index()[0]
```

Trying to replicate the required results :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:[5.0,54.0,3.0,9.0], 1:[6.0,12.0,6.0,12.0], 2:[9.0,76.0,np.nan,41.0], 3:[8.0,2.0,12.0,100.0]})
df.loc[4] = ['','','','']
    0   1    2    3
0   5   6    9    8
1  54  12   76    2
2   3   6  NaN   12
3   9  12   41  100
4         

df = df.replace('',np.nan).dropna(how='all') #to remove blank rows
df.stack(dropna=False).reset_index()[0]
0       5.0
1       6.0
2       9.0
3       8.0
4      54.0
5      12.0
6      76.0
7       2.0
8       3.0
9       6.0
10      NaN
11     12.0
12      9.0
13     12.0
14     41.0
15     100.0
```

Comment: I think you're doing what he wants, just a small detail:
df.stack drops the NA values in the df, so then when you stack the df the index will be mixed up.

df.stack(dropna=False) will do the job I think

Comment: I tried your solution for the first part and it worked, but for the second one the output didnt change

Comment: Could you try now ?

Comment: nothing extra to try :), I already mentioned in the edit that your suggestion didnt work, thanks for the help though.

Comment: Sorry it did not work out. I have tried to replicate your question above with a few rows of the input dataframe which you provided. Could you check if it is the same ?

Comment: I am really thankful for your constant help, now after executing 
file = file.replace('',np.nan).dropna(how='all')
the extra row of with empty values (the became NaN) is gone.However when running file.stack(dropna=False).reset_index()[0] and then displaying the dataframe "file" the output still looks as rows and columns not as one whole row

Comment: Ok. If it is fine, could you let me know what is the set of commands which you are using ?

Comment: oh, omg my bad i was executing the command  file.stack(dropna=False).reset_index()[0]
but then displaying the dataframe itself not the stacked one. so it worked but can you explain a little bit about the command to be able to know when to use it,

Comment: Glad it worked ! The stack command reshapes the dataframe, following by reset_index ( which changes the index ). Then, we select the column named `0`. One way to find out what is happening is to run each part of the command separately ( separated by dots ).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if `pd.read_csv("excel data.csv", skip_blank_lines=True, header=None)` will work?

Comment: skip_blank_lines=True is True by default, so if he were using read_csv he would have got it right I think

Comment: as bernardo said, i tried skip_blank_lines and nothing changed